# Querying a Database with Phone Number Comparison

Tags: java, android, database, phone-number

I'm aware that it requires an external library (like libphonenumber...or simply PhoneNumberUtils) to compare two phone numbers when a variety of country exit/entry/local area codes are involved.  Given this fact, I'm wondering how to efficiently query a database for all the phone numbers in a user's phone book if it's not an option to query for ALL phone numbers in the db then compare them afterwards (using PhoneNumberUtils) because there are simply too many numbers in the db.  Is there a way to build that phone number comparison offered by libphonenumber/PhoneNumberUtils into the database query?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your question is too broad to be properly answered here. Perhaps use your google-fu and find something and throw some code together and see what works and if you run into an error. Flagging to close.

Comment: Well you are very open in how you are describing this. What kind of database? MySql, Mongo, another type? It is just very broad in how it is worded. If using MySql or something you can definitely pull the data and there are dozens of resources on how to do this. Once you have the data you can use any library to compare that you want. I just think you are asking this too broadly and will draw primarily opinion based answers. If you actually read point 4 in the SO FAQ you can see this outlined.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Jordan, thank you for your response, but as I said in the question "Note: it's not an option to query for ALL phone numbers in the db then compare them afterwards because there are simply too many numbers in the db."  Your answer suggests to do exactly what I said cannot be done.  My question is not about the specifics of the query (be it MySql, Mongo, or anything else).  My question is about comparing phone numbers in a db on a theoretical level.

Comment: Well I'm sorry I'm failing to understand fully I guess. PhoneNumberUtils offers a compare method that can compare the phone numbers once you get them. You'll still need to query to get them but thats an option. If that doesn't help perhaps someone else will add input! http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#compare%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Jordan, agreed, that's what I tried first - to query the phone numbers then use the compare functionality of PhoneNumberUtils.  The problem is that if you have 100,000 phone numbers in your database, you are pulling 100,000 phone numbers every time just to compare them to the couple dozen in the user's phonebook (the query ends up taking so long that the phone crashes half the time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally worked out an answer to this in case anyone is interested.  There isn't a way to build the phone number comparison into the database query - you need to parse all numbers beforehand and put them into a standard format (probably e164) using something like libphonenumber.  Once they are all in a standard format in the database, querying against them is simple.